# `java` command is not found from this Python process. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`

Tags: java, python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I don't know how to fix this error when I'm trying to run the following code:

```
df = wrapper.read_pdf(r'C:\End_to_End\1902\PN\Scenario1_AllCorrectMin\EPR.pdf')
```

Log:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py in read_pdf(input_path, output_format, encoding, java_options, pandas_options, multiple_tables, **kwargs)
    107     try:
--> 108         output = subprocess.check_output(args)
    109 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    335     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 336                **kwargs).stdout
    337 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    402 
--> 403     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    404         try:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    996                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
--> 997                                          startupinfo)
    998             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JavaNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-010e34a004ec> in <module>()
----> 1 df = wrapper.read_pdf(r'C:\End_to_End\1902\PN\Scenario1_AllCorrectMin\EPR.pdf')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py in read_pdf(input_path, output_format, encoding, java_options, pandas_options, multiple_tables, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     except FileNotFoundError as e:
--> 111         raise JavaNotFoundError(JAVA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR)
    112 
    113     except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:

JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

I tried changing and creating the path in the environmental variables but did not work. Here is the screenshot:

[image: System_Properties]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have java version 8 (Checked through about java)

Answer (score 12):

Under the `System Variables` click `Path` and then press the `Edit...` instead of `New`. Then in the next screen (`Edit environment variable` for the Path variable) click `New` and add the address, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin`. Press `OK` and the Path variable will be appended/updated.

You will need to restart your environment (e.g. Chrome, Anaconda, etc) for the path to have effect.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add Java to the `path` variable (look at [this question](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) in Java Help Center), not create a new one. Also, make sure you're properly referencing a file to read, looks like your log threw a FileNotFound exception.

Comment: I tried the link and couldn't figure out which file I should refer to.  The one used was C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin, but did not work. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I too faced the same issue on my work PC while trying to read table data from a PDF, using `tabula`. The following process helped me overcome this issue.

I also used [amazon corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/), which is basically an openJDK. Free to use and install, maintained by Amazon.

Install it in `C:\` drive.

Now, go to `environment variables` in system properties. Under `system variables`, double click `Path` and click `New` add the path like this `C:\Users\20195579\amazon-corretto-11.0.12.7.1-windows-x64-jdk\jdk11.0.12_7`

Also add new variable in `system variables`. `Variable Name: JAVA_HOME` `variable value: C:\Users\20195579\amazon-corretto-11.0.12.7.1-windows-x64-jdk\jdk11.0.12_7` See below images.
[image]

Should look like this after adding:
[image]

Incase still facing issue, add Oracle javapath to `Path` in `system variables`. like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`

checked both on work PC and personal PC, worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you do not already have Java installed on your computer, this code will not work. i can confirm as i was previously not running Java and experiencing the issue, then when i downloaded Java and added it to PATH (as described in the solution above), it worked.

Summary:

1. download & install java (copying the install location)
2. add install location to the PATH variable in advanced system settings

Comment: Note that the question specifies that Java is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue based on my experience, I am sharing here.

Step 1 - After download and completed installation of Java (copy a bin path location and add into environment variables)
[image: bin location]

Step2 - Add Java PATH location in the environment variable.[image]

Still you are getting same error restart your anaconda and Chrome or restart you pc.

Check below code in command prompt

```
java --version
```

Complete Java installation and environment variable path setting up guidance video - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJ-PJbvJBGs).

Answer (score 0):

on linux distribution
type in console:
`>sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`
that work for me.

Answer (score -1):

The following video is a tutorial that addresses this issue: https://youtu.be/Sbic3aMCwhY?si=swWMwYUwoxU8ekSR.

Note:

1. I downloaded Amazon Corretto as recommended by Deepak Harish's comment. You can download this at the official website: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/windows-7-install.html.
2. I did not refer to any .bin files. Referring to the folder containing Amazon Corretto worked fine.

Hope this helps. Good luck!