# converting Python Script to EXE with (Tabula) .JavaNotFoundError using Auto Py to EXE

Tags: python, java, tabula, auto-py-to-exe

So I made a script that downloads a pdf from the web (via selenium), then converts said pdf table to an excel file (via tabula). I would want to share this script with people in the office however my team does not have any python/programming experience so I decided to convert the python file into an executable using Auto-Py-to-EXE. I then added a file (chromedriver) and it successfully downloaded the file.

For the conversion I used tabula to convert the PDF to a csv and xlsx file. (in the notebook/.py, the conversion worked) but when I converted the .py into an exe and ran the executable I ran into the error below.

```
  File "tabula\io.py", line 80, in _run
  File "subprocess.py", line 493, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "erc_scraper.py", line 126, in <module>
  File "tabula\io.py", line 322, in read_pdf
  File "tabula\io.py", line 91, in _run
tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
[24568] Failed to execute script 'erc_scraper' due to unhandled exception!
```

So I tried adding my java path to the environment path by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817211/java-command-is-not-found-from-this-python-process-please-ensure-java-is-inst). I've added the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin` to the `JAVA_HOME`, `JAVA`, and `PATH`.

However, now I'm getting this error when I try to execute the EXE file.

```
Error from tabula-java:
Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\ur7634o\Desktop\erc_scraper\tabula\tabula-1.0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\ur7634o\\Desktop\\erc_scraper\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'C:\\Users\\ur7634o\\Desktop\\ERC Data\\pdf\\qualified_contestable_customers_20220221-11-09-36.pdf']' 
returned non-zero exit status 1.
[25240] Failed to execute script 'erc_scraper' due to unhandled exception!
```

Any advice what to do next? It seems the executable cannot read the file? I'm thinking how to make this easy also for the end-users to do this. I was just hoping the end-users can double click some shortcut to initiate the downloading and conversion of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem today, I tried this and it worked:

- when you compile your executable, use "One Directory" option
- after you are done compiling, go to the directory of your tabula package installation, copy that tabula folder into your output folder of auto-py-exe
  [tabula package location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdPv2.png)

that should work. What's missing is "tabula\tabula-1.0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar" just as the error indicated. I'm not sure why auto-py-to-exe doesn't bring the tabula package over like the other packages, but I had to bring it over manually.